# Why does referencing an unique_ptr behave this way?

Tags: c++, reference, unique-ptr

```
vector<int> v1, v2;

/*1*/        vector<int> &someReference=v1;     //compiles
/*2*/        someReference=v2;         //compiles

vector<unique_ptr<int>> vec1, vec2;

/*3*/        vector<unique_ptr<int>> &otherReference=vec1;    //compiles
/*4*/        otherReference=vec2;     //ERROR
```

I would understand if neither line 3 nor 4 didn't compile, but the third one doesn't cause any compilation errors - apparently there are no problems with initializing the reference for the first time and passing it around; the problem only appears when I try to assign it the second time.

I can't understand what is going on behind the scenes that makes the second assignment impossible.

Comment: google "move semantics"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has nothing to do with references, it's the `unique_ptr` that cannot be copied.

```
unique_ptr<int> p1, p2;
p1 = p2; // error
```

Consequently, vectors of `unique_ptr` cannot be copied either.

```
vector<unique_ptr<int>> vec1, vec2;
vec1 = vec2; // error
```

Comment: You're right, that was a silly mistake. I guess it means that it's impossible to change the reference itself, too bad.

Comment: @Adrian17 Right, a reference is an alias to something else, and it is always bound to that something. You cannot change what it aliases.

Comment: @Adrian17 `T&` can be thought of as a `T*const` (note: the pointer is `const`, what we point to is not) that overrides `operator=` to dereference-and-assign (and similarly for other operators, from `.` through to `+`), and overrides the constructor to take-address-of-and-store.  This isn't a perfect model, but it is a useful one nonetheless.  Or we could talk about pointer-vs-reference-vs-value semantics on copy/construct/move/move-construct if you prefer.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are assigning `vec1` to `vec2`, and this cannot be done because the contents of the vectors are not assignable.

This

```
otherReference=vec2;
```

is exactly the same as

```
vec1 = vec2;
```

because `otherReference` is an alias for `vec1`. Wherever you see `otherReference` in an expression, you can replace it by `vec1`.

Answer (score 0):

Initialising a reference is *very* different from assigning to it. When you *initialise* a reference, you set it to refer to an object. Everywhere thereafter, using the reference actually means using the referred object. This means that assigning to the "reference" actually means assigning to the referred-to object.

And in your case, the assignment is illegal, because `std::unique_ptr` cannot be copied (so, by extension, neither can a vector of them, of course).